# What is the diefference between ComboViewer and Combo?

Tags: java, swt, jface

What is the difference between `JFace` entities and `SWT` controls they wrapping?

```
ComboViewer -> Combo/CCommbo

TableViewer -> Table

ListViewer -> List
```

and so on.

Comment: Please don't be shy to study their respective Javadoc. The difference in their APIs, therefore their functionality, is evident.

Comment: Not for me. I see it is different. But what are principles?

Comment: On the left are JFace's MVC components, on the right are the raw SWT widgets.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432112/swt-table-vs-tableviewer) seems very related.

Answer (score 2):

ComboViewer, TableViewer and ListViewer are part of the JFace Viewers. JFace Viewers simplify the mapping of a data model to a visual representation. If you have a data model then JFace Viewers are the easier API to work with.